# Jar file with packaged images exported from Eclipse not running

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I exported a runnable jar file from the Eclipse IDE. In Eclipse the program works fine, but when exported the program refuses to open. To clarify, the images are in a source folder and loaded via URL through a resource loader class. I used JD-GUI to show the contents of my jar file and the images are packaged properly into the file (Picture of this included). Why is the jar file not running properly?
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPrFR.png)

Here is my code for the URL Loader

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{
  BufferedImage img1, img2;
  URL url1 = ResourceLoader.class.getResource("1.jpg");
  URL url2 = ResourceLoader.class.getResource("2.jpg");
  MainPanel(){
    try {
        img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
        img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img1, 1, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(img2, img1.getWidth(), 0, null);
    if(g instanceof Graphics2D){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the resource loader class

```
final public class ResourceLoader {

    public static InputStream load(String path){
        InputStream input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        if (input == null) {
            input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+path);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Edit:://
Here is the command prompt read-out for the error that is happening
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfdeA.png)

Comment: "Refuses to open"?  No error message? What do you see when you open the program using `java -jar testFile2.jar` on the command line?

Comment: What's the problem? What happens when you compile and run the app? Do you get any errors? If so, please post them.

Comment: Also, ensure your jpg's file name extensions are lower case, just like you wrote them in your strings.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited the post so that the error from the program being run in the command prompt is shown in an image.

Comment: You should copy and paste the error message in your question directly. I suggest checking out the link given at the top of your question. If that doesn't help you fix the problem, edit your question to explain why not. On a side note, using a `static` method in `ResourceLoader` is probably not appropriate. A more object-oriented design would make this a non-static method.

Answer (score -1):

While exporting the jar select the class that contains main method in "Launch Configuration. It should work fine. If you still face problem then run jar from command line using "java -jar jarfilename" command to see the exact error message.